# Rack middleware global middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, middleware, rack-middleware

Can someone please explain how this peace of code works, especially the log filter part.
I want to assign `log_attributes_filter` from the rack file, where i calling `use MongodbLogger::RackMiddleware`, how to do so?

```
# Rack middleware for mounted rack app (e.g Grape)
module MongodbLogger
  class RackMiddleware
    @@log_attributes_filter = nil

    def self.log_attributes_filter=(filter)
      @@log_attributes_filter = filter
    end

    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      request = ::Rack::Request.new env
      path = request.path.split('/')
      log_attrs = {
        params:     request.params
      }

      log_attrs = @@log_attributes_filter.call(log_attrs) if @@log_attributes_filter

      logger.mongoize(log_attrs) do
        return @app.call(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Before i simply used it as `use MongodbLogger::RackMiddleware`, but now i want to filter some params, how should i properly assign `@@log_attributes_filter`?

Comment: From reading http://mongodb-logger.catware.org/ and https://github.com/le0pard/mongodb_logger it seems that filters are set via the web-interface, I don't think you need to write anything specific here, unless you want to extend it beyond it's current capabilities. If that's the case I might consider reaching out to smotsovoy as he wrote that patch https://github.com/le0pard/mongodb_logger/pull/48 .

Answer (score 0):

Found a way.

```
  use MongodbLogger::RackMiddleware
  MongodbLogger::RackMiddleware.log_attributes_filter = lambda do |request|
    begin
      request[:params]["Password"] = "[FILTERED]"
      request
    rescue
      request
    end
  end
```